# Sortable on null id in laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I try to make sortable function for my categories and I'm using `JQuery UI`

## Logic

1. If category `category_id` is null it means that category is parent.
   (in my case i used `category_id` instead of `parent_id` just
   different naming)
2. Categories going maximum 2 deep like `Parent->child 1->child 1
   childs`

## What I try to do

update `category_id` column when I drop and drop one of my categories by Ajax

## Issues

1. I'm getting `404` error on network
2. My function doesn't support null `category_id`

## Codes

```
@foreach($Categorys as $cat)
//parent (deep 0)
<li class="parent" id="{{$cat->id}}">
{{$cat->title}}

//first child (deep 1)
@if(count($cat->childs))
@foreach($cat->childs as $child)
<li style="margin-left:20px !important;" class="firstchild" id="{{$child->id}}">
{{$child->title}}

//first child child (deep 2)
@if(count($child->childs))
@foreach($child->childs as $childdd)
<li style="margin-left:40px !important;" class="secondchild" id="{{$childdd->id}}">
{{$childdd->title}}
</li>
@endforeach

@endif
</li>
@endforeach

@endif
</li>
@endforeach
```

`Ajax`

```
$(function() {
    $('.mytest').sortable({
        stop: function() {
            $.map($(this).find('li'), function(el) {
                var itemID = el.id;
                var itemIndex = $(el).index();


                if (itemID) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '{{ url('
                        categorysort ') }}/' + encodeURI(itemID),
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: {
                            itemID: itemID,
                            itemIndex: itemIndex
                        },
                    });
                } else {
                    console.log(data);
                }

            });
        }
    });
});
```

`route`

```
Route::post('/categorysort/{id}','CategoryController@UpdatecategoryparentByAjax')->name('categorysort');
```

`controller`

```
public function UpdatecategoryparentByAjax(Request $request, $id)
    {
      $categories = Category::orderby('id', 'desc')->get();

      $itemID = $request->input('itemID');
      $itemIndex = $request->input('itemIndex');

      foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $category->where('id', $itemId)->update([
          'category_id' => $itemIndex,
        ]);
      }
    }
```

> PS: I'm aware that there is missing `category_id` data in my `li's` the
>   reason i didn't put that is because I didn't know how to should I use
>   it exactly, as I mentioned before in my issues my function doesn't
>   support that yet (so I need your helps please).

`screenshot`

[image: screen1]
Thanks.

Comment: is this line generating correct urls ?
            `url: '{{ url('categorysort') }}/'+encodeURI(itemID),`

Comment: @MasoudHaghbin i tried it in address bar it returns error `Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found. `

Comment: What's the created URL?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir is become something like `mydomain.test/categorysort/0/2` I assume the extra number in url is because of parent category `itemID` which i passed only one in my ajax url. so i'm a bit confused now :)

Comment: What does the `url: ...` line look like in the HTML source code? Or, what's the result of `{{ url('categorysort') }}`?

Answer (score 1):

It might be because you aren't protecting agaisnt csrf, which is mandatory when doing a post request so, as [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token) explain you could solve by adding this to your html:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Then in your ajax you would only need to append it as a header.

```
$.ajax({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        url: '/categorysort/'+ itemID ,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {itemID: itemID, itemIndex: itemIndex},
      });
```

Also you are only recieving 1 id so I guess that what you are trying to do is sort depending on the parent, therefore you should only select the `li` with parent class, that way your controller will recieve 1 id instead of 2 because what you are doing right now is `/categorysort/{parentId}/{childId}` and what you would need is `/categorysort/{id}`, so instead of selecting all categories just select the top parent categories:

```
$.map($(this).find('.parent'), function(el)
```

Comment: no man `csrf` error is `419` i'm getting error `404` is related to my items id's can't define which is what and how to manage them when it gets them, I need changes in controller and ajax code, `however` thanks for suggestion.

Comment: I'll update my answer asuming that what you want is to sort the parent category

Comment: Would you mind share full code? I'm not sure where to put your second code in my ajax.

Comment: What second code?  My second code is the line(4th) you have for selecting all of the `li` and instead of li I switched it to  `.parent` so you only select top_parent categories

Comment: Also note that I switched your 'url' of the ajax because php and javascript shouldn't be mixed

Comment: I'll give it a try and let you know what happens.

Comment: when I use `.parent` instead of `li` i'll lose ability of drag&drop I think `JQuery UI` works on li's only.

Comment: it's the selector you are changing, and .parent corresponts to li of top parent categories I don't see why it should fail, have you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

After see your comments about `encodeURI(itemID)`, I know the problem is your `route.php`.

> I'm getting 404 error on network

You need to update your route with [**optional parameters**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-parameters) :

```
Route::post(
    // Add {second_id?}. This is an "optional parameter".
    'categorysort/{first_id}/{second_id?}', 
    'CategoryController@UpdatecategoryparentByAjax'
)->name('categorysort');
```

So, you can access :

- `mydomain.test/categorysort/1`
- `mydomain.test/categorysort/1/2`

If you need 3rd `id`, add more **optional parameters** like this :

```
Route::post(
    'categorysort/{first_id}/{second_id?}/{third_id?}', 
    'CategoryController@UpdatecategoryparentByAjax'
)->name('categorysort');
```

So, you can access :

- `mydomain.test/categorysort/1`
- `mydomain.test/categorysort/1/2`
- `mydomain.test/categorysort/1/2/3`

If you want to make `first_id` do the same thing, just add `?` after `first_id` like `{first_id?}`.

---

> My function doesn't support null category_id

After update your route, your just need call :

```
public function UpdatecategoryparentByAjax(Request $request, $first_id, $second_id, $third_id)
{
    // $first_id      access your 1st ID
    // $second_id     access your 2nd ID 
    // $third_id      access your 3rd ID

    // Do some logic here..
}
```